# Clear cache in Symfony: `cache:clear` or `rm -rf`?

Tags: php, symfony

Which is the difference between `./bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` and `rm -rf var/cache/prod/*`? Console command is very slow. Bash command is fast. So, ... why use `cache:clear` instead of `rm`?

Comment: You'll read everywhere this is better to use `php app/console blahblah`, `php app/console make coffee`, `php app/console make my dreams come true`. The "official" best approach should be: `php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata && php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  && php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result`. Dont believe what they say. I had apache as a reverse proxy, then I had varnish, then nginx, and I've upgraded in all versions of symfony from 2.3 until 3 now and it **never ever** worked properly. Never ever. The actual and effective solution? In my next comment

Comment: ...The actual and effective solution? `rm -rf ./app/cache/dev/* ; rm -rf ./app/cache/prod/*` then restart your webserver, whatever it is to empty the cache. This is the only effective method. Not the best, not the "follow the best practices, believe in Santa Claus, believe in perfection", but the one that works. And I probably guess that's why it's written "better done than perfect" on Facebook walls. I have my cache clear and **it works**. I'm seriously fed up with the "only use `php app/console`" hype. And if you're under Windows you'll always end up this way, believe a 4yo Symfony user.

Comment: agree with the `rm -rf` that works perfectly. Only problem is the impossibility to delete some file that are in use, that I solved by launching the command more than once

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`cache:clear` wipes previously created cache items, but **also**, it does a cache warm-up. Upon this, you application should load very fast due to the fact that cache was already pre-populated.

On the other hand, `rm -rf` does only one part of the job. You should notice performance impact when you try to load you app the first time after this.

I would also like to point out another thing: permissions. If you are logged in as `root` for example, and you did not set access rights via `setfacl` (or any other method), `cache:clear` will most probably create your cache items owned by `root`. This could be an issue, down the line.

Hope this helps a bit...

Answer (score 13):

"cache:clear" command not only removes the cache but they usually build the updated cache data (warm up) so that symfony does not have to create one after the first request comes, which is the reason that it takes more time than the mere removal of files under your cache folder by "rm -rf". 
Even if you can finish that command faster, it would take time for you to process the first request, if you have not created cache in advance by this command.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html

So, usually it is better to run cache:clear, at least in the whole process of deployment.
The occasion you would use rm command is usually only when some file permissions have gone wrong (i.e. maybe you had run a command with a wrong user ) and there were no choices left, I think.

Answer (score 5):

You better use the "official" best approach that it using `cache:clear` not using `rm`...follow the best practices
and here almost all commands:

```
  cache:clear                             Clears the cache
  cache:pool:clear                        Clears cache pools
  cache:warmup                            Warms up an empty cache
  doctrine:cache:clear-collection-region  Clear a second-level cache collection region.
  doctrine:cache:clear-entity-region      Clear a second-level cache entity region.
  doctrine:cache:clear-metadata           Clears all metadata cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query              Clears all query cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query-region       Clear a second-level cache query region.
  doctrine:cache:clear-result             Clears result cache for an entity manager
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this list of commands explain the difference between using `rm` and any of them?

Comment: I just suggest `cache: clear` for removing cache.... not using `rm`. that's it.

Comment: Please do that in your answer. You haven't suggested anything, you've just listed a bunch of commands