# Symfony cache:clear error ruined my whole project

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a simple project in Symfony 5.2 and I wanted to install composer mailer for user registration, so I ran:

```
composer require symfony/mailer
```

But when it was executing `cache:clear`, it returned an error and suddenly I could do nothing in my project, maker-bundle is not working and if I run server it throws an error:

```
In App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php line 429:
                                                                                                                                                                  
  Warning: require(C:\Users\Javi\Dropbox\DAW\GeoSport\var\cache\dev\ContainerTtp0Lx5\getVarDumper_ContextualizedCliDumper_InnerService.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                  

list [--raw] [--format FORMAT] [--] [<namespace>]
```

Error when I run `symfony server:start`:
[image: server_start_error]

Comment: Try to delete cache manually - remove everything inside ```C:\Users\Javi\Dropbox\DAW\GeoSport\var\cache\dev\```.

Comment: `C:\Users\Javi\Dropbox` - have you checked whether the Dropbox client interferes with this? Cleaning the cache removes a lot of files, and maybe Dropbox can't handle this?

Answer (score -1):

Once in a while you will get that error.
Something went wrong during your cache clear and the cache is out of sync. Some cache files are still there and refer to already removed cache files.
Best is to manually clear your cache folder
This has turned out to be the best solution over the years for me.

So basically it is manually clearing the cache folders yourself via command line

```
 # For Mac: -r means "recursively" and -f means "forced"
 rm -rf route/to/var/cache
 
 # For Windows: /s means "include subdirectories" /q means "forced without asking"
 rmdir /s/q route/to/var/cache
```

**And watch out with that command. It is dangerous.** When accidentally pressing enter when you are still typing the folders, you can have serious damage . So maybe type the route/to/var/cache first and then go prefix it with the command.

Cleaning out the cache folder manually is actually almost the same as doing a cache clear without warmup. [Info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40281629/5418514)

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know it was that easy to clear cache, command is running on his own after installing dependencies and it destroyed my project T.T

Comment: Please share more details. As the error message states, the cache is already clean. Why should cleaning it again help? Also, `rm -rf` might not work on Windows

Comment: No the cache is not clean. As you can see in the image the "require ..." (middle of the error) of a cache file happens inside another cache file (top of the error). But I updated my answer with more information and added Windows command.